# A sufficient condition to ensure a symmetric matrix to be zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. Suppose the sum of all $1\times 1$  principal minors is zero, the sum of all $2\times 2$  principal minors is also zero. Show that $A$ is zero.

I know only that for $v=(1,\cdots,1)$, $vAv^t=0$.

Comment: use fact that for  symmetric matrice $A=A^T$

Comment: I still could not derive anything...

Answer (score 1):

This condition means that the characteristic polynomial has the form

$$\chi(A) = x^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-3}a_i x^i.$$
Such a polynomial either has at most $n-1$ real roots, or is zero, which you can see by differentiating a bunch of times.

Comment: @How can I get the result "the polynomial has at most $n-1$ real roots" by differentiating?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the characteristic polynomial is the trace of $A$, but not the sum of all $1\times 1$ principal minors...Alas. So the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ may not be zero.